# R shiny: Align inputs/ outputs horizontally within columns

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to align inputs/ outputs horizontally within columns. I can do this by splitting IDs, but I would prefer a way that dynamically splits the single input/ output ID into spaced columns.

Here is my code:

```
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
rm(list = ls())

ui <-  navbarPage('Example',id = "inTabset",
                  tabPanel(title = "Example_1", value = "Example_1",
                           fluidPage(
                               tags$b( h4("Example_1", align = "left")),
                             theme = shinytheme("paper"),
                             fluidRow(
                               column(6,checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label ="", 
                                                           choices = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                                                           selected = c(1,4,7)) )
                              ),
                             br()
                           ),
                           hr(),
                           verbatimTextOutput("example1")
                  ),
                  
               tabPanel(title = "Example_2", value = "Example_2", 
                                         fluidPage( 
                                           tags$b( h4("Example_2", align = "left")),
                                           br(),
                                           fluidRow(   
                                             column(4, uiOutput("VarsInput")),
                                           fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("dataInfo")),
                                           br(),
                                           hr())    
                                )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$example1 = renderPrint(input$checkGroup)
  ### output$example2 = ????
  ### i.e what data (a,b,c,d,e or f) has been chosen from the selectInput below? 
  
  
  K <- reactive({
    length(input$checkGroup)
  })
  
  output$VarsInput <- renderUI({
    NoV = K()
    C = sapply(1:(ceiling(NoV)), function(i){paste0(input$checkGroup[i])})
    
    output = tagList()
    for(i in seq_along(1:ceiling(NoV))){
      output[[i]] = tagList()
      output[[i]][[1]] = selectInput(C[i], C[i], c("",c("a","b","c","d","e","f")))
      }
    output
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As an example, the first input looks like this:
[single column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3YD1.png)

I could, of course, split this into 2 (with the following code) to look like the following picture. However, this entails creating a separate ID, which I want to avoid.

[2 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xlgD.png)

```
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
rm(list = ls())

ui <-  navbarPage('Example',id = "inTabset",
                  tabPanel(title = "Example_1", value = "Example_1",
                           fluidPage(
                               tags$b( h4("Example_1", align = "left")),
                             theme = shinytheme("paper"),
                             fluidRow(
                               column(6,checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup1", label ="", 
                                                           choices = c(1,2,3,4),
                                                           selected = c(1,4)) ),
                               column(6,checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup2", label ="", 
                                                           choices = c(5,6,7,8),
                                                           selected = c(7)) )
                              ),
                             br()
                           ),
                           hr(),
                           verbatimTextOutput("example1")
                  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$example1 = renderPrint(input$checkGroup1)
  
  output$example2 = renderPrint(input$checkGroup2)
 

 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Set `inline = TRUE` in your `checkboxGroupInput`

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, that doesn't attain the UI I'm going for of just splitting it into 2 columns.

Comment: @Graham With your second option, you could combine the results from both inputs in a `reactive` expression pretty easily. Are there other reasons you want to avoid the second `inputId`?

Comment: Thanks, @Ben. That's still an option yes. I just wondered if there is a way to do it without manually dividing content into columns, particularly if several columns are required.

Answer (score 1):

Using `inline=TRUE` with `width="100px"` will control how wide you want to display.  Then use

```
tags$head(
    tags$style(
      ".checkbox-inline{margin-left:10px;"
    )
  )
```

to indent the first row.  Try this

```
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
rm(list = ls())

ui <-  navbarPage('Example',id = "inTabset",

                  tabPanel(title = "Example_1", value = "Example_1",
                           fluidPage(
                             tags$b( h4("Example_1", align = "left")),
                             theme = shinytheme("paper"),
                             fluidRow(
                               column(6,checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label ="", width="100px", inline=TRUE,
                                                           choices = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                                                           selected = c(1,4,7)) )
                             ),
                             br()
                           ),
                           hr(),
                           verbatimTextOutput("example1")
                  ),
                  tags$head(
                    tags$style(
                      ".checkbox-inline{margin-left:10px;"
                    )
                  ),
                  tabPanel(title = "Example_2", value = "Example_2", 
                           fluidPage( 
                             tags$b( h4("Example_2", align = "left")),
                             br(),
                             fluidRow(   
                               column(4, uiOutput("VarsInput")),
                               fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("dataInfo")),
                               br(),
                               hr())    
                           )
                  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$example1 = renderPrint(input$checkGroup)
  ### output$example2 = ????
  ### i.e what data (a,b,c,d,e or f) has been chosen from the selectInput below? 
  
  
  K <- reactive({
    length(input$checkGroup)
  })
  
  output$VarsInput <- renderUI({
    NoV = K()
    C = sapply(1:(ceiling(NoV)), function(i){paste0(input$checkGroup[i])})
    
    output = tagList()
    for(i in seq_along(1:ceiling(NoV))){
      output[[i]] = tagList()
      output[[i]][[1]] = selectInput(C[i], C[i], c("",c("a","b","c","d","e","f")))
    }
    output
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for your help, @YBS. How would I go about widening the gap between the columns to look like my two column example?

Comment: Sorry, I have not tried that.  It may require javascript adjustment and I am not that familiar with js.  Also, you can update the `checkboxGroupInput()` as your own function with slightly different name and use it.